# How to fix an Invariant Violation in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Essentially I am getting an Invariant Violation error:

`React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

`Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

What I have done is gone into the `index.js` file and passed through my `SideBar Component`. When I do this, the SideBar pops on the screen without having to click the `toggleButton` so I know it works. However, when I pass it through the `App.js` class component I get these errors.

App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

import ResumePage from './pages/resume/resume-page.component';
import NavBar from './components/nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
import HomePage from './pages/homepage/homepage.component';
import ProjectsPage from './pages/projects/projects.component';   
import FooterNav from './components/footer/footer.component';
import {SideBar} from './components/sidebar/sidebar.component'; 



class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      sideBarOpen: false
    } 
  }

  sideBarToggleClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState ((prevState) => {
      return {sideBarOpen: !prevState.sideBarOpen};
    })
  } 

  render() {
    let SideBar; 
    if (this.state.sideBarOpen) {
      SideBar = <SideBar />; // passing in the SideBar component here 
    }
    return (
      <div className="App" style={{height: '100%'}}>
        <Switch>
          <NavBar sideBarClickHandler={this.sideBarToggleClickHandler} />
          {SideBar}
          <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
          <Route path='/resume' component={ResumePage} />
          <Route path='/projects' component={ProjectsPage} />
          <FooterNav />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Functional ToggleButton component

```
import React from 'react'; 

import './toggleButton.styles.scss';

const ToggleButton = props => (
   <button className='toggle-button' onClick={props.click}>
       <div className='toggle-button_line' />
       <div className='toggle-button_line' />
       <div className='toggle-button_line' />
   </button>
); 

export default ToggleButton;
```

The expected result will be to have the sidebar pop up when I click the toggleButton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Components` **must** return either `jsx` or `null`, you are returning `undefined`. Initialize your variable

```
let SideBar = null
```

You could also use a `ternary operator` to conditionally assert a value to a `const` like this

```
const Sidebar = this.state.sidebarOpen ? <Sidebar /> : null
```

Also `SideBar` from your `import` will conflict with `let SideBar`. You need to rename one of those

```
import { SideBar as SideBarComp } from './foo'
```

Or

```
let SideBarComp = null
```

Here is a working example of your sandbox

[image: Edit react-portfolio]

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give this a try!

Comment: So I did both, no luck. When I set the ```SideBar = null``` it came back with the same Invariant Violation error except instead of undefined it told me it was null. Second, the ternary operator created a new ```ReferenceError: Cannot Access SideBar before intialization```.

Comment: Now it's because both variables have the same name. change to `let Content` or something else, and you should be good to go!

Comment: Even if one section is commented out? I commented out my previous ```If Statement``` and replaced it with the ```ternary operator statement```. Also, I am placing the ternary operator statement inside of the ```render method```. Is the the correct location?

Comment: Nop, the `import` is the problem. `import {SideBar} from './components/sidebar/sidebar.component'` you could also rename it like this `import {SideBar as SideBarComp} from './components/sidebar/sidebar.component'`

Comment: This is getting convoluted. I'm updating the answer

Comment: Alright, so I made the suggested changes and still not getting it to work.

Comment: Could you please share a sandbox?

Comment: Can I share my github repo?

Comment: Of course! Just need to take a look in the code as a whole

Comment: Nvm I figured out the sandbox - heres the URL - https://codesandbox.io/s/github/alxdelgado/react-portfolio/tree/master/?fontsize=14

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me understand this error. It's greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help. Welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Sidebar is undefined if the condition isn’t met. Initialize it to null.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing a component into a variable, you can simply conditionally render your component,

```
{this.state.sideBarOpen && <SideBar />}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qajyks)